# Issue in HQL queries?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

This is a test program. Table in the database is student with id and name as columns. POJO class is Student with id and name as properties

HQL query used in servlet1 is:

```
List<Student> l = ses.createQuery("select s.id, s.name from Student s").list();

        out.println("Database students are as follows:<br/>");
        Iterator it= l.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Object o[]= (Object[]) it.next();
            out.println("Student id is :"+o[0]);
            out.println("<br/>");
            out.println("Student name is :"+o[1]);
            out.println("<br/>");
        }
```

HQL query in servlet2 is:

```
List<Student> l=ses.createQuery("from Student").list();
        out.println("Database students are as follows:<br/>");
        Iterator it= l.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Student s= (Student) it.next();
            out.println("Student id is :"+s.getId());
            out.println("<br/>");
            out.println("Student name is :"+s.getName());
            out.println("<br/>");
        }
```

In servlet1 if i use Student object instead of Object class object the data is not retrieved from the database why?, viceversa everything works fine.

In sevlet2 if i use Object class object instead of Student object the data is not retrieved from the database why?, viceversa everything works fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your first query has multiple clause that you could not convert to List because id and name are different type. So it will be List type.

For your second query, you are returning list of student so you should not convert it to Object type then back to Student type again. For more information please follow link here- https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/04/25/java-persistence-query-return-types.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you are calling `l=ses.createQuery("from Student").list();` you are retrieving the full set of columns from the DB and there the `Student` class can be properly instantiated.

Comment: ok. in l = ses.createQuery("select s.id, s.name from Student s").list(); why Object class is used and why not Student class?

Comment: I am guessing that hibernate assumes that as you are using columns then you may not be using all available columns.

Comment: ok. why object class is used when hibernate is not able to determine all the columns are used or few columns are used?

Comment: what do you suggest it uses?

Comment: i suggest the columns id and name should be used because that is what am specifying in the query ( l = ses.createQuery("select s.id, s.name from Student s").list();). But my question is why Object class and why not Student class in servlet1?

Comment: Sorry maybe I did explain well.  As you are specifying columns, then unless Hibernate goes and checks (using reflection) to make sure all columns are being specified, it has no other way to know that all columns are being specified.  I guess the overhead here is just too much.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet 1 & 2:

```
 List<Student> l = ses.createQuery("select s.id, s.name from Student s").list();
```

that query is return list of object,so you need mentioned what kind of Object your are going to retrive.

it return Student < Id , Name > Object

```
 ses.createQuery("select s.id, s.name from Student s").list();
```

if your trying to use

```
 List<Object> it also return your Student(base object of list) Object.but it not good.so,we specifically mentioned what exact format Object type.
```

both cases,your need to perform Casting Operation.

```
 List<Student> l =(List<Student>) ses.createQuery("select s.id, s.name from Student s").list();
 List<Object> l =(List<Object>) ses.createQuery("select s.id, s.name from Student s").list();
```